# how to update a JTable with Combo box which is in a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jdialog

i have created a window that includes a jtable that is populated with mysql data. there is also a button 'LOAD TABLES' when clicked a Jdialog pops up letting the users to chose another table from the JComboBox! everything works pretty fine but the problem is when a table is chosen from JComboBox and clicking the Jdialog OK button the JTable is not loading the data from the new table (Not refreshing)!! Below is simplified code!!

Any help please!!!!

class mysqlData extends JFrame
{

```
Font buttonFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 16);
Font labelfont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 24);
Connection connecting;
public String tableName = "Examination";

static final String Select = "Available Mysql Tables";



//connection statements
mysqlData()
    {
        Connections con = new Connections();
        connecting = con.connect;
        System.out.print("value of input is: " + tableName);


    }



    //creating jtable and populating it with data from mysql database
    public JScrollPane dataTable() throws SQLException
    {

        Statement st = connecting.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("Select * from " + tableName);
        ResultSetMetaData md = result.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<String> column = new Vector<String>();

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong username or password" + tableName,"Failed!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        DefaultTableModel tablemodel = new DefaultTableModel(data,column);
        tablemodel.setRowCount(0);
        tablemodel.setColumnCount(0);

        for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
        {
            tablemodel.addColumn(md.getColumnName(i));
        }

        while(result.next())
        {
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>(columnCount);

            for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
            {
                row.add(result.getString(i));
            }

            tablemodel.addRow(row);
        }



        JTable table = new JTable(tablemodel);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900,780));
        JScrollPane scrolPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        return scrolPane;
     }




    //a button that pops up a jdialog and lets users to select a table from jcombo box
    public JButton tablesButton()
    {
        JButton tablesListButton = new JButton("LOAD TABLES");
        tablesListButton.setFont(buttonFont);
        tablesListButton.addActionListener(listener);

        return tablesListButton;
    }



    //actionlistener for the  tablesButton

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String[] tables  = new String[]{"Attendance","Examination","Students","Subjects","Teachers","Salary"};
            tableName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mysqlData.this,"Please select your favorite sport",Select, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,tables,"Attendance");


        }
    };
```

}

Comment: What are you doing with the results from `dataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some refactoring on your example due to compilation error. 
Code below should work:

```
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String[] tables = new String[] { "Attendance", "Examination", "Students", "Subjects", "Teachers", "Salary" };

        tableName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Please select your favorite sport", "Attendance",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
                        tables, tables[0]);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected: " + tableName);

        System.out.println("value of input is: " + tableName);
    }
};
```

For future reference, here is set of JOption/InputPane examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

HTH

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!! but it is not the answer! I want to refresh the JTable with the new value of tableName;

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a lot of refactor i think , i'll give you some hints to do that.

1) The main problem is that in your ActionListener when a table

```
tableName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mysqlData.this,"Please select your favorite sport",Select, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,tables,"Attendance");
```

You are doing anything with it , you have to refresh your `tableModel`. You have to call again

```
Statement st = connecting.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("Select * from " + tableName);
        ResultSetMetaData md = result.getMetaData();
```

And you have to take access to your current `JTable` something like

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)jtable.getModel();
for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
        {
            tablemodel.addColumn(md.getColumnName(i));
        }

        while(result.next())
        {
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>(columnCount);

            for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
            {
                row.add(result.getString(i));
            }

            tablemodel.addRow(row);
        }
```

Instead of creating a new instance of a jtable everytime, you only want to change the model.